Replace NA values with values from cells on the right in R
I have a data frame with sets of NA values between data, like this:
first.row <- c("2015-01-21","negative","negative","positive","2015-02-27","negative","negative","2015-05-23","negative","negative","2016-04-07","negative","negative","positive")
second.row <- c("2015-03-10","negative","negative","positive",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2016-02-11","negative","negative","positive")
third.row <- c("2015-05-21","positive","negative","positive",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2016-04-18","positive","negative","positive")
headers <- c("Date1","Value1a","Value1b","Value1c","Date2","Value2a","Value2b","Date3","Value3a","Value3b","Date4","Value4a","Value4b","Value4c")
data.frame <- rbind(first.row,second.row,third.row)
colnames(data.frame) <- headers
And I need try to replace NA values with values from the right if sets of NA begins in some date column. So I would like the following result:
first.row.output <- c("2015-01-21","negative","negative","positive","2015-02-27","negative","negative","2015-05-23","negative","negative","2016-04-07","negative","negative","positive")
second.row.output <- c("2015-03-10","negative","negative","positive","2016-02-11","negative","negative","positive",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
third.row.output <- c("2015-05-21","positive","negative","positive","2016-04-18","positive","negative","positive",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data.frame.output <- rbind(first.row.output,second.row.output,third.row.output)
colnames(data.frame.output) <- headers
Any suggestion would be very appreciate.
